# Collect text in mdframed and print at the bottom of the next page

Tags: cross-referencing, mdframed, atbegshi

I am trying to collect say fruits mentioned in a page and print them at the bottom of the next page. All text is always enclosed in a frame and the frame can span multiple pages but the collected fruits always have to be printed at the bottom of the next page after being mentioned in a page. The problem is that if two frames start on a page and the fruits inside the second frame appear in the next page they will be printed together with that of first frame but that shouldn't be the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{collect}

\newenvironment{fruit} {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\collectfruits}\x}{\endcollect}

%to print to bottom of next page after fruits named on page
\newcommand{\printbottomNext}[1]{
{\LARGE print on bottom of next page\\}
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0.1\paperwidth,-0.95\paperheight){#1}%
  }%
}
}

\definecollection{fruits}

\newcommand\collectfruits{%
\collect{fruits}
{}
{}
{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[frametitle=with apple and orange]

 \blindtext[3]
\begin{fruit}
apple
\end{fruit}

\begin{fruit}
orange
\end{fruit}

\printbottomNext{\includecollection{fruits}}
\blindtext[2]

\end{mdframed}


\blindtext[3]
\begin{fruit}
pineapple
\end{fruit}

\begin{fruit}
 banana
\end{fruit}
\printbottomNext{\includeco llection{fruits}}
\blindtext[2]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```